# postgresql.conf file found in both /usr/share/postgresql and /etc/postgresql/

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

While troubleshooting [another issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/124054/34332) I noticed that in my Ubuntu 14.04 system there are two `postgresql` directories containing a `postgresql.conf` file:

- /usr/share/postgresql
- /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/

With the following directory structure:

```
$ tree -d /usr/share/postgresql
/usr/share/postgresql
├── 9.3
│   ├── extension
│   ├── man
│   │   ├── man1
│   │   └── man7
│   ├── timezonesets
│   └── tsearch_data
└── 9.4
    └── man
        ├── man1
        └── man7
```

... and:

```
$ tree -d /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/
/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/
```

With the `postgresql.conf` files residing in the following locations:

- /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/postgresql.conf
- /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

By using `SHOW config_file;` I have verified which configuration file my server is using:

```
postgres=# SHOW config_file;
               config_file                
------------------------------------------
/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

My question is why do I find the `postgresql.conf` file in two locations and is the above an indication of some unused installation or other unused artifacts I ought to purge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files below `/usr/share/postgresql/` are supposed to be data files that are not meant to be edited. They are not live configuration files.

The FHS spec at https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard
defines /usr as:

> /usr/
>
> ```
> Secondary hierarchy for shareable, read-only data (formerly from UNIX source repository, now from UNIX system resources)
> (files that are not-required to boot or rescue the system)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> /usr/share/ : Architecture-independent (shared) data
>
> [...]

On the other hand, files under `/etc/postgresql/X.Y/main` are the live configuration files for a PostgreSQL cluster named `main` with version X.Y, such as created by the command `pg_createcluster`. Each cluster (=each postgres instance) has its own `postgresql.conf` that is generated with it, as the other writable configuration and data files of that cluster.

Personally, on my Ubuntu 14.04, I don't find a `postgresql.conf` under /usr.
There is however a template file at `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/postgresql.conf.sample`, but note the `.sample` suffix.

That file belongs to the `postgresql-9.3` package, as revealed by `dpkg -S`:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/postgresql.conf.sample
postgresql-9.3: /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/postgresql.conf.sample
```

It's also consistent with
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/postgresql-9.3/filelist

You may try `dpkg -S postgresql.conf` on your system and check if `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/postgresql.conf` is part of the results, and if yes, to what package it belongs, and then what is the origin of that package. Maybe for some reason it's the same as the sample postgresql.conf, except it doesn't have the `.sample` suffix.

Comment: It's quite likely that I copied the `postgresql.conf.sample` file as `postgresq.conf` myself in the same directory (`/usr/share/postgresql`) erroneously thinking that I was meant to edit that file with my specific configurations.